# Is there a way to start reading an ESDS file from 10th record in an IBM Mainframe batch program?

Tags: batch-file, cobol, mainframe, vsam

Given:

The ESDS file has record length of 80.

It has 200 records.

I have checked the following links, however didn't get a satisfactory answer.

[IBM Mainframe Forum](http://ibmmainframes.com/viewtopic.php?t=160&start=0&postdays=&postorder=&highlight=)

[Geekinterview](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/65279)

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Any code ? What do you want to do with the data read ? Alternative approaches based on built-in programs of Windows accepted ?

Comment: The ESDS file contains text? Records of 80 characters with no <CR><LF>'s?

Comment: I have not used COBOL for a while now, but I guess you can't do that in batch COBOL. You can do this in CICS though.

Comment: Have a count, filter out the first n-1 records on the file, and you processing will start at n. What if there aren't at least n records on the file? Why would you want to do this? As well as very easy to solve, it doesn't seem a particularly useful thing to be doing.

Comment: @Marged the batch-file tag is misused. Program is running on an IBM Mainframe under z/OS. Leaving the tag in the hope of garnering close votes more easily.

Comment: @Aacini the records could contain anything. Certainly not terminated by anything (they will be fixed-length, or variable-length with a byte-count).

Comment: @EmmadKareem don't say that,  you'll have OP asking "how do I call a CICS program from a Batch program?" :-)

Comment: @BillWoodger I thought the file was downloaded to PC ...

Comment: @Marged well, it is certainly an question lacking in detail. Just for information, if an ESDS file (dataset) were transferred to a PC, the EBCDIC-to-ASCII translation would break it, and even if left as EBCDIC you'd need to write your own code to understand the Virtual Storage Access Method (see the Redbook *VSAM Demystified* for details if really, really interested).

Comment: @BillWoodger thanks for that detail. After having downloaded lots of fixed length files full of COBOL code to my PC I left the Mainframe field for good back in the late nineties ;-)

Comment: @BillWoodger, The file has records for sure which is checked in previous step. We have to read the records one by one first to iterate the counter. How can we directly go to record number 10 without reading the first 9 records? Is it possible?

Comment: It is time you clearly specify what you want. Do you want to process the file in Mainframe? Do you want to use it on a PC? Which compiler do you use on the PC? Why uses ESDS if you want to access the file randomly? What is the big deal in skipping the first n records in a sequential file any way? It would take less than a second on any platform....

Comment: You  can't do what you want in native IBM COBOL. Now what?

Answer (score 2):

That is an odd requirement, but if you want to process away nine standard headers or something, the easiest way is to do nine reads when you open the dataset.  E.G.

```
Open My-ESDS
Perform Read-My-ESDS 9 times
Perfomr Do-Normal-Stuff
```

There are other options available -- you could read the file as "unformatted", which makes you deal with everything about the format.  I do not recommend this unless you really need some very specific file handling.

If you don't need the first nine records, you could sort/drop them before kicking off your program, that is easy and easily maintained.

Can you give any idea why you want to skip the first nine and start at the tenth?  It might make a difference...

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I wanted to mention that what the original poster wanted to do is easy, but you need an assembler language or C/C++ subroutine. The trick is the VSAM POINT macro - an assembler program can call it directly, and the C runtime "fseek()" function does pretty much the same thing. If you're skipping a small number of records, it's not a big deal, but if you needed to point halfway through a large file, POINT is the way to do it.